# PreparedStatements or callableStatements

Tags: java, jdbc

I tried to understand the difference between `PreparedStatements` & `CallableStatements` and I couldn't get it. so please can anyone convert following `sql` Query to `CallableStatement`. I know how to convert Statement into a `PreparedStatement` but having problems with `CallableStatements`.

as a `java.sql.Statement`

```
SELECT * FROM Customer WHERE customerId = 'C001'
```

as a `java.sql.PreparedStatement`

```
SELECT * FROM Customer WHERE customerId = ? //set customerId using preparedStatement.setString(1,"C001")
```

How to write this same query in `CallableStatements`

Thanks in advance!

Comment: CAllablestatement used for StoredProcedure Activities.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JDBC - Statement, PreparedStatement, CallableStatement and caching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8371053/jdbc-statement-preparedstatement-callablestatement-and-caching)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As stated in the [CallableStatement API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/CallableStatement.html):

> The interface used to execute SQL stored procedures.

And as such, it can not be used to execute queries.

Answer (score 1):

Callable Statements are used for accessing stored procedures.

You have to write stored procedure in database

for

```
SELECT * FROM Customer WHERE customerId = 'C001'
```

And

please look into the following links to have help on callable statements -

1 > http://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/jdbc-callablestatement-stored-procedure-out-parameter-example/

2> http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jdbc/callablestatement-object-example.htm

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

check this

[DIfference Between Stored Procedures and Prepared Statements..?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7296417/difference-between-stored-procedures-and-prepared-statements)

CallableStatement used for mainly StoredProcedure